# Spring boot .AnnotationConfigApplicationContext has not been refreshed yet error

Tags: spring-boot, configuration

Currently have the following classes in spring boot application

```
Class A {
 
    @Bean
    Jackson2JsonObjectMapper objectMapper() {
  
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(xxxx);
 ......
...
        return new Jackson2JsonObjectMapper(mapper);
    }
 
 @Bean
    xxxx addxxxx(
            SomeClass class,
            Jackson2JsonObjectMapper objectMapper
    ) {
       ..do someting.
return xxx
          
}
```

The above was working fine until I introduced

```
@Configuration
Class B {
 
@Bean
Declare BeanC
 
}
```

After introducing the above class, it creates the bean in ClassB but it gives the following error :

> "Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
>   'standardJacksonObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer' parameter 1; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'spring.jackson-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonProperties':
>   Could not bind properties to 'JacksonProperties' :
>   prefix=spring.jackson, ignoreInvalidFields=false,
>   ignoreUnknownFields=true; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@657c8ad9
>   has not been refreshed yet"

I also implemented the following solution but it did not work

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
 
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(ClassB.class);
        ctx.refresh();
    }
}
```

Any suggestions to resolve would be appreciated.